# How to add a specific path for FTP user home?

Tags: ssh, ftp, vsftpd

I installed recently vsftpd and added a user called ftpuser. I created the /etc/vsftpd.conf file from scratch with the following info:

```
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
local_root=/mnt/md0
secure_chroot_dir=/mnt/md0
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=NO
pasv_enable=Yes
pasv_min_port=10000
pasv_max_port=10100
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

I also added the ssh server for sftp connections. I managed to login just fine but whenever I log in, I don't see the desired drive which is located in /mnt/md0 but the generic ftp user homefolder. In fact I see both ftpuser and the homefolder for the admin which is not to be desired.

So how can I tell vsftpd.conf to show the ftpuser only the /mnt/md0 exclusively?

I tried so far:  sudo adduser ftpuser --home /mnt/md0
Warning: The home dir /mnt/md0 you specified already exists.
adduser: The user `ftpuser' already exists.

Thanks!

edit:

> sftp -P 2222 -vvvvvvv ftpuser@PUBLIC IP

shows

```
...
debug3: Sent message fd 3 T:16 I:1
debug3: SSH_FXP_REALPATH . -> / size 0
sftp> ls
debug3: Sending SSH2_FXP_READDIR I:3
debug3: Received reply T:104 I:3
debug3: Received 4 SSH2_FXP_NAME responses
debug3: Sending SSH2_FXP_READDIR I:4
debug3: Received reply T:101 I:4
debug3: Received SSH2_FXP_STATUS 1
debug3: Sent message SSH2_FXP_CLOSE I:5
debug3: SSH2_FXP_STATUS 0
ftpuser  su       
sftp> cd ftpuser
debug3: Sent message fd 3 T:16 I:6
debug3: SSH_FXP_REALPATH /ftpuser -> /ftpuser size 0
debug3: Sent message fd 3 T:17 I:7
debug3: Received stat reply T:105 I:7
sftp> ls
debug3: Sending SSH2_FXP_READDIR I:9
debug3: Received reply T:104 I:9
debug3: Received 9 SSH2_FXP_NAME responses
debug3: Sending SSH2_FXP_READDIR I:10
debug3: Received reply T:101 I:10
debug3: Received SSH2_FXP_STATUS 1
debug3: Sent message SSH2_FXP_CLOSE I:11
debug3: SSH2_FXP_STATUS 0
FTP-TEST
```

Comment: That is done with `local_root=/mnt/md0` + `allow_writeable_chroot=YES` + `chroot_local_user=YES` so you might have a different problem then you think. Try to connect from command line and add `-vvvvvvv`  as an option. That will echo tons of info on screen. Don't forget to restart `vsftpd` though :)

Comment: The part behind those flags is more important ;) remove the comment! no idea if there is any private data in there ;-) I have copied the last part that I would consider important from it. I did not see any issues in there :) `sftp> cd ftpuser` is probably the important one (and `SSH_FXP_REALPATH /ftpuser -> /ftpuser size 0`)

Comment: I think I omitted private data! The issue is the fact that I can LOG IN but the home path is not what is supposed to be. It's not the /mnt/md0 drive/folder combo. It's the  standard ftp directory.